# Selenium webdriver code working in Firefox, but not working in IE and Chrome

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

Selenium Gurus,

I am a newbie and struggling to make it work. I have a piece of code which works perfectly in Firefox; but not working in IE and Chrome.
This is the code:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//img[contains(@src,'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==')])[10]")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//img[contains(@src,'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==')])[17]")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//img[contains(@src,'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==')])[34]")).click();

    WebElement oWE=driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//img[contains(@src,'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==')])[34]"));

    Actions oAction=new Actions(driver);
    oAction.moveToElement(oWE);
    oAction.contextClick(oWE).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

Basically what the code does is after login, it does a drill down by expanding the tree.
First it goes to 10th element in the tree, then the 17th and finally 34th element.

This Xpath code works fine in Firefox and it goes and clicks the "+" icon in the tree and it keeps expanding to child levels. The same code where as in IE and Chrome, for the 10th element, it selects someother element from the tree and its stops there.
Does not proceed further and it says "No Such Element Exception".

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards
Sarah

Comment: If the same Xpath works differently in different browsers, first check whether the page source changes *per browser*. Specifically (1) Is there an `img` element at all in Chrome/IE? (2) Does the alphanumeric portion of your img `@src` (that is the `R0lGODlhAQABAI` part) change with each browser, or perhaps each run of your code?

Comment: Please share your HTML code snippet for better understanding.

Comment: @Vish thanks for the reply.I compared the page source of firefox and chrome they were same except for the tokens. img src (that is the R0lGODlhAQABAI part) remains the same.

Comment: I used Xpath helper to find the Xpath in chrome but it was too long...

Comment: /html[@class='x-strict x-viewport']/body[@id='ext-gen1020']/div[@id='panel-1104']/div[@id='panel-1104-body']/div[@id='sharedSelectionComponent']/div[@id='sharedSelectionComponent-body']/div[@id='panel-1105']/div[@id='panel-1105-body']/div[@id='neFilterPanel']/div[@id='neFilterPanel-body']/div[@id='neFilterPanel-innerCt']/div[@id='neFilterPanel-targetEl']/div[@id='neTreePanelContainer']/div[@id='neTreePanelContainer-body']/div[@id='neTreePanel']/div[@id='neTreePanel-body']/div[@id='treeview-1117']/table[@id='treeview-1117-table']/tbody[@id='treeview-1117-body']

Comment: /tr[@id='treeview-1117-record-151']/td[@id='ext-gen2699']/div[@class='x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-treecolumn']/img[@class=' x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-plus x-tree-expander']/@src

Comment: @AbhishekYadav here is the html code.<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-plus x-tree-expander">

Comment: I have added my solution, please review and if it is suitable for you accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to solve your problem:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//tr[2]//img[1]")).click();
//above code is to click on root element of tree

driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//tr[4]//img[2]")).click();
//above code is to click on child element of tree

driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//tr[5]//img[3]")).click();
//above code is to click on subchild element of tree
```

> Above code is tested for Firefox and Chrome both using the link
>   http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/tree/treegrid.html

Answer (score -1):

Check the HTML generated in both browser. For chrome and firefox you can check the XPATH using developer tools.

Run the code in debug mode or see if any exception is thrown in case of IE or chrom while finding the element.